# append values of same id with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, append

I'm new on xsl transformation and really didn't find a solution for my problem on the web.

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<xml>
<id>1</id>
<value>abc</value>
<id>1</id>
<value>def</value>
<id>2</id>
<value>xyz</value>
<id>2</id>
<value>hij</value>
.
.
</xml>
```

Now i need a xml that has appended values like:

```
 <xml>
<id>1</id>
<value>abc, def</value>
<id>2</id>
<value>xyz, hij</value>
.
.
</xml>
```

Could anyone help me on this issue how to do this with a xslt?

I don't have exactly the format i gave you.
Actually it looks like this:

```
<xml>
<objects>
<record>
<attribute>
<id>1</id>
<valuegroup>
<value>abc</value>
</valuegroup>
</attribute>
</record>

 <record>
<attribute>
<id>1</id>
<valuegroup>
<value>def</value>
</valuegroup>
</attribute>
</record>

 <record>
<attribute>
<id>2</id>
<valuegroup>
<value>hij</value>
</valuegroup>
</attribute>
</record>

 <record>
<attribute>
<id>2</id>
<valuegroup>
<value>xyz</value>
</valuegroup>
</attribute>
</record>
</objects>
</xml>
```

Sorry for my inattention.

Comment: Consider to ask a new question with the new input format and the corresponding output format you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XmlPrime you can use

```
<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="value" group-by="preceding-sibling::id[1]">
      <id><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></id>
      <value><xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator=", "/></value>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="xml/value" use="preceding-sibling::id[1]"/>

<xsl:template match="xml">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="value[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', preceding-sibling::id[1])[1])]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
  <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::id[1]"/>
  <value>
    <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', preceding-sibling::id[1])">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>, </xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
```